# How to sum values in an object of an array?

Tags: php

With this:

```
$obj1 = [
    "101" => 18,
    "102" => 15,
    "103" => 23,
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-17 00:00:00"
];
 
$obj2 = [
    "101" => 15,
    "102" => 13,
    "103" => 79,
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-18 00:00:00"
];
$obj3 = [
    "101" => 50,
    "102" => 50,
    "103" => 62,
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-19 00:00:00"
];
$testArray = [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3];

// add Total
$withTotal = [];
$total = 0;
foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    array_push($withTotal, $value);
    $total += array_sum($value);
    $withTotal[$key]['total'] = $total;
}
```

I get:

```
[
  {
    "101": 18,
    "102": 15,
    "103": 23,
    "timeSummary": "2023-04-17 00:00:00",
    "total": 2079
  },
  {
    "101": 15,
    "102": 13,
    "103": 79,
    "timeSummary": "2023-04-18 00:00:00",
    "total": 4209
  },
  {
    "101": 50,
    "102": 50,
    "103": 62,
    "timeSummary": "2023-04-19 00:00:00",
    "total": 6394
  }
]
```

but I need the `$total` be the SUM of `101, 102, 103`. `101, 102, 103` are dynamic so these keys will be different.

I try to exclude timeSummary but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if (!$withTotal[$key]['timeSummary']) {
                $total += array_sum($value);
            }
```

Comment: `array_sum` is getting a number from your `timeSummary` keys. Notice the total in the first one is `18 + 15 + 23 + 2023 == 2079`. Make sure to exclude those before summing the values, or even store the values under a separate array (`"values": [18, 15, 23, ...]` or separate section (`"values": { "101": 18, ... }`)

Comment: how do I exclude `timeSummary`?

Comment: look at the contents of  $key before adding $value to to sum.   check for not a number, check that string character 1 is not a digit, ....

Comment: At its most basic you could just loop over the keys, using `continue` if you find `"timeSummary"`, or adding to the tallied result otherwise. There's also [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) that can make a fine solution as well. Programming is not guess-work, you can't just throw words at it and hope it works. Read up the documentation for what you're using.

Comment: Do not keep both the individual values and metadata or aggregate values on the same level. Try something like `$obj1 = [ "data" => [ "101" => 18, "102" => 15, "103" => 23, ], "timeSummary" => "2023-04-17 00:00:00"]`. Then do `$obj1['total'] = array_sum($obj1['data']);` and so on.

Comment: Why is it so hard to exclude `timeSummary`?

Comment: iterate and sum. exclude properties you don't intend to sum.

Comment: maybe use `array_filter` to filter non-numeric fields ... like in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
<?php
    $obj1 = [
        "101" => 18,
        "102" => 15,
        "103" => 23,
        "timeSummary" => "2023-04-17 00:00:00"
    ];
     
    $obj2 = [
        "101" => 15,
        "102" => 13,
        "103" => 79,
        "timeSummary" => "2023-04-18 00:00:00"
    ];
    $obj3 = [
        "101" => 50,
        "102" => 50,
        "103" => 62,
        "timeSummary" => "2023-04-19 00:00:00"
    ];
    $testArray = [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3];
    foreach ($testArray as $key => $arr) {
        $sum = array_sum(array_filter($arr,"is_numeric"));
        $testArray[$key]['total'] = $sum;
    }
    print_r($testArray);
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/8cec8

Comment: Do note this solution can be brittle if you add another value that _is_ numeric but shouldn't be included. Similarly excluding fields you don't want can also be brittle for the same reason. In the long run, you should aim for @axiac's solution if possible, but I can understand if you're stuck in that format for reasons beyond your control.

Comment: This almost works. Except when it is executed the second time using as input the output of a first execution. On the second execution it also adds the value of `total` computed on the first execution. It also fails if more properties whose values must not to be summed are added to the objects.

Comment: @axiac, for my purpose I need to count all numeric values that are coming in. I'm in control what is coming through the query but I'm not in control what the front-end should be as that is decided by a framework. So I can not use your solution because the front-end would either need some serious adjustments or won't work as expected.

Comment: @Grasper I'm not asking to use my solution. I understand your situation. I am just trying to make everyone aware that code that seems to work fine today may suddenly stop working correctly because of side changes that it does not take into account (I gave two examples in my previous comment.) Do what you think it's better for your code. We're not walking in your shoes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$testArray = [
  [
    '101'         => 18,
    '102'         => 15,
    '103'         => 23,
    'timeSummary' => '2023-04-17 00:00:00'
  ],
  [
    '101'         => 15,
    '102'         => 13,
    '103'         => 79,
    'timeSummary' => '2023-04-18 00:00:00'
  ],
  [
    '101'         => 50,
    '102'         => 50,
    '103'         => 62,
    'timeSummary' => '2023-04-19 00:00:00'
  ]
];

$result = array_map(
  static fn($obj) => $obj +
    [
      'total' => array_sum(
        array_filter(
          $obj,
          static fn($key) => $key !== 'timeSummary',
          ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
        )
      )
    ]
  ,
  $testArray
);
```

Comment: This almost works. Except when it is executed the second time using as input the output of a first execution. On the second execution it also adds the value of `total` computed on the first execution. It also fails if more properties whose values must not to be summed are added to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up unsetting `timeSumary` setting the Total and then setting `timeSummary` again.

```
$withTotal = [];

foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    $total = 0;
    array_push($withTotal, $value);
    unset($withTotal[$key]['timeSummary']);

    $total += array_sum($withTotal[$key]);
    $withTotal[$key]['total'] = $total;

    $withTotal[$key]['timeSummary'] = $testArray[$key]['timeSummary'];
}
```

Comment: you don't need to unset it, check my answer, seems to be cleaner

Comment: This almost works. Except when it is executed the second time using as input the output of a first execution. On the second execution it also adds the value of `total` computed on the first execution. It also fails if more properties whose values must not to be summed are added to the objects.

Comment: The total gets reset to 0 on second execution. My SELECT statement won't allow other properties to be added except those mentioned here.

Answer (score -2):

Do not keep the data on the same level as the metadata and the aggregated values. Put the data in a separate list property, as below:

```php
$obj1 = [
    "data" => [
        "101" => 18,
        "102" => 15,
        "103" => 23,
    ],
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-17 00:00:00"
];
 
$obj2 = [
    "data" => [
        "101" => 15,
        "102" => 13,
        "103" => 79,
    ],
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-18 00:00:00"
];
$obj3 = [
    "data" => [
        "101" => 50,
        "102" => 50,
        "103" => 62,
    ],
    "timeSummary" => "2023-04-19 00:00:00"
];
$testArray = [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3];

// add Total
$withTotal = [];
$total = 0;
foreach ($testArray as $obj) {
    // compute the total for this object
    $obj['total'] = array_sum($obj['data']);
    // add it to the big total
    $total += $obj['total'];
    // put the updated object in a new array
    array_push($withTotal, $obj);
}

print_r($withTotal);
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/OArj6).

Comment: I can't separate data like that. I'm using ExtJs and that requires the objects in the same level otherwise the grid will create another row..

Comment: Then you need a way to tell apart the values that you want to add from those that you don't want to add. PHP functions `is_int()` or `is_numeric()` are not an option, the operation should produce the same result when it is executed the second time on the already processed data.